# How to apply a matrix to an image in opencv?

Tags: c, opencv, computer-vision

Say I have some image and a rotation matrix and translation vector that I want to apply to that image.  How do I apply that in opencv?

My assumption is that I have some 3D points (where I have x,y,relative z) and the associated rotation matrix (which is a 3x3 matrix), where I wish to multiply each point by the rotation matrix, to have it "act" on the points.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV has a *warp affine* function for this purpose.

OpenCV 1 (old API):

```
cvWarpAffine(&srcImage, &dstImage, &mat2x3) ;
// dst size will be same as src size.
```

OpenCV 2 (new API):

```
cv::warpAffine(&srcImage, &dstImage, &mat2x3, cvSize(dstWidth, dstHeight)) ;
```

Comment: the matrix has to be 2x3?  This doesn't make sense when applying a 3D rotation or translation

Comment: Yes, the matrix stores basis vectors for 2D rotation and translation since an image is a projection on a 2D plane. Please update your question to explain what kind of 3D transformation you would like to achieve and what are your assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

For a 3x3 you can/should use cv::warpPerspective.

```
cv::warpPerspective( image, warpedImage, warpMat, destinationSize );
```

I'm not sure if there's a performance reason to do so but...

You can use warpAffine as well, but you actually have to convert that matrix into a 2x3 before warping. The opencv API makes a pain-in-the-ass to do.

```
cv::Mat af0 = affine2x3.row( 0 ); // cannot copy directly for some reason
affine3x3.row( 0 ).copyTo( af0 ); 

cv::Mat af1 = affine2x3.row( 1 ); 
affine3x3.row( 1 ).copyTo( af1 );

cv::warpPerspective( image, warpedImage, affine2x3, destinationSize );
```

If there's an easier way, I'd love for someone to correct me...